# Getting "find . proc/xxxx no such file or directory" while i am trying to retreive the backup file

Tags: bash, scripting

When I try to search for a file using the command :

```
find . -name $tar_file_name -type f -print0|xargs -0
```

it gives me those errors :

```
find: ‘./proc/12049’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./proc/20958’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./proc/21062’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./proc/21073’: No such file or directory
```

Could anyone tell me the reason and possible solutions to solve this ?

Comment: These looks to me `/proc` will have pids files which could have removed till find's result reached out to xargs so at that time it till give errors, add `2>/dev/null` to your command to get rid of it.

Comment: `/proc` is a special directory (https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html), you should either exclude it or ignore those find errors.

Answer (score 4):

If you `man find`, you could find the below option `-ignore_readdir_race`.

```
 -ignore_readdir_race
              Normally,  find  will  emit  an error message when it
              fails to stat a file.  If you give this option and  a
              file  is deleted between the time find reads the name
              of the file from the directory and the time it  tries
              to  stat  the  file, no error message will be issued.
              This also applies to files or directories whose names
              are  given  on  the  command line.  This option takes
              effect at the time the command line  is  read,  which
              means that you cannot search one part of the filesys-
              tem with this option on and  part  of  it  with  this
              option  off (if you need to do that, you will need to
              issue two find commands instead, one with the  option
              and one without it).
```

It will be the best practice to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

`/proc` contains the pids information in files so once a processes's work is done it's pid file will be removed from there. Take it as this way when `find` ran then `/proc/some_pid` was present and it has taken in it's memory but when output reached out to `xargs` as standard input at that time those files were removed since processes would have completed so it is giving an error there since it is not able to find it in system. To remove errors from screen you could do following then.

```
find . -name "$tar_file_name" -type f -print0 2>/dev/null |xargs -0
```

Or if you DO NOT want to remove all errors(which above command does) then better ignore `/proc` path itself from `find` command then.

```
find . ! -path '/proc' -name "$tar_file_name" -type f -print0 |xargs -0
```

Answer (score 1):

Prevent traversal of the proc filesystem by using the "prune" action. Note that the "not" (!) operator won't work in this case, as the proc filesystem will still be traversed, leading to the "No such file or directory" errors.

To prevent traversing the proc filesystem when executing the find command, use
`-path /proc -prune`

Note that when "prune" is the only action in the find command, the command will (perhaps counter-intuitively) show the files that have been pruned instead of ignoring those files.

From the find man page:

> If the expression contains no actions other than -prune, -print is performed on all files for which the expression is true.

To prevent this, one should use the "print" action: `-path /proc -prune -o -print`
The print option has to be added after other options that narrow down the search, for instance `-path /proc -prune -o -name file_to_find -o print`. If the "exec" action is being used, for instance, the "print" action is not required.